# Javascript Video loadmetadata event not being triggered on React-Redux Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video, dom-events

I have a React-Redux application that reads some metadata from videos.

However the code added to the `loadmetadata` event is never triggered.

As a workaround I have added a timer to wait 1 second before, which is a pretty bad solution and doesn't work every time.

Another thing is that I couldn't find an elegant way to integrate the video element into Redux code without having to manipulate the DOM.

The code looks like this:

```
  videoPlayerElement = document.getElementById(`videoplayer-${videoId}`);
  videoPlayerElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
      const duration = videoPlayerElement.duration;
      ...
  })
```

The code inside the listener is never executed.
I also have tried different ways to assign the loadmetadata event, i.e: assigning directly to `videoPlayerElement.onloadmetadata` still not working.

I thought it might be because of the scope of the object, so I changed it to a global just for testing... didn't help.

Any other idea about what might be causing?

If I run a simple example, like [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/AUSNu/1/) it works fine.

Comment: Are you rendering the videoPlayerElement with your react app or where does it come from?

Comment: Yes, it is been rendered in a React component.
Forgot to mention, when I log the object after calling the getElementById the video object is there.

Comment: They why don't you use [react synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)? Generally you should avoid selecting elements from the DOM if don't have to. I will provide an example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about them!

Comment: Why people keep downvoting without even have a decency of explaining their reasons?

Comment: This is a really good question. In my opinion if you downvote you should explain why and what has to be improved. While you question may be basic for some people I can't see why it should be downvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In react you should use [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) where possible. Example for your use case:

```
class MediaPlayer extends Component {

    handleMetadata = event => {
        const duration = event.currentTarget.duration;
        // ...
    }

    render() {
        const {src} = this.props;

        return(
            <video src={src} onLoadedMetadata={this.handleMetadata} />
        );
    }
}
```